# Extract separate a text with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

This a source code from a website: http://www.example.com and I want to extract with scrapy crawler all THIS IS A TEXT.

```html
<tr>
<td>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;padding-left:4px;" class="category">  <imgsrc="http://www.example.com/images/menu.gif"> 
        THIS IS A TEXT </td>
   </tr>
                               <tr>
       <td class="date" colspan="5">THIS IS A TEXT</td>
   </tr>
                               <tr>
       <td style="test-align:left;width:40px;">THIS IS A TEXT</td>
       <td style="padding-right:4px; width:180px;text-align:right">
       THIS IS A TEXT </td>
                                       <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"> <nobr><a id="I1" name="I1"
href="javascript:MoreInformation(1,'1141','1563513','TT','home');">
       THIS IS A TEXT</a></nobr>
        </td>
       <td style="padding-left:5px; width:180px;text-align:left">
       THIS IS A TEXT </td>
       <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"></td>
   </tr>
                               <tr>
       <td style="test-align:left;width:40px;">THIS IS A TEXT </td>
       <td style="padding-right:4px; width:180px;text-align:right">
       THIS IS A TEXT </td>
                                       <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"> THIS IS A TEXT  </td>
       <td style="padding-left:5px; width:180px;text-align:left">
       THIS IS A TEXT </td>
       <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"></td>
   </tr>*
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is my scrapy_project.py:
I tried to extract everything from td:rows = hxs.select('.//td') , I don't know how to extract separate "This is a text".
I receive this mistake: u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t. Someone can help me please?

```py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from dirbot.items import Website

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/",
        "",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@id="content"]//table/tr')
        items = []

        for row in rows:
            item = Website()
            item ["job"] = row.select("td[1]/text()").extract()
            item ["description"] = row.select("td[0]/a/nobr/text()").extract()
            item ["name"] = row.select("td[2]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Another question: how can eliminate this: `u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`

Comment: _I don't know how to extract separate "This is a text"_ is not clear to me. Having said that, `td[0]/a/nobr/text()` will not match anything since positions in XPath start at `1`. `u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'` is simply leading whitespace from the selector's extraction. You can use `.strip()` method to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters. If you can, you should use more acurate selectors for your `TD`s, such as `td[@class="category"]` or `td[@class="date"]`

Comment: I try: rows = hxs.select('//td[@class="category"]/a/@href') but I receive error: 'raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
        exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:'  can someone tell where I'm wrong?

Comment: can you post your stack trace/console log? (to some pastebin service preferably) What code line(s) generates this error? Are you generating `Request`s?

Comment: My error is: **exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'**   My code is: **item ["job"] = row.select("//text()").extract().strip('u,\t,t')**

Comment: Try `item ["job"] = map(unicode.strip, row.select("//text()").extract())`

Comment: Thenks very much for your help. How can to extract separate "This is a text". I try with: hxs.select('//table//tr//td[@class="category"]') . Someone can help me please?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the real HTML of the page and telling us what parts you want to extract. The example source with the same "THIS IS A TEXT" everywhere makes it difficult to understand what you are trying to scrape. Surely your target page has some structure.

Comment: Html page that I want to extract is the same as the real one I just replaced structure with: THIS IS A TEXT

HTML where I want to extract the source code is posted above. Thanks again!

Comment: Still not sure if I understand your problem but what does `[e.strip() for e in hxs.select('//td//text()').extract()]` or `[e.strip() for e in hxs.select('//td/text()').extract()]` look like for you?

Comment: Your code work, thanks, but I want to extract like this: **for row in rows:
            item = Website()
            item ["row1"] = row.select("td[1]text1").extract()
            item ["row2"] = row.select("td[2]text2").extract()
            item ["row3"] = row.select("td[3]text3").extract()
   
   items.append(item)
   
        return items**

Comment: Thanks Paul for your help. Why can not extract more than three **item [" job "] = row.select (" td [1] / text () "). extract ()**. If you insert the four **item ['jobs'] = row.select (" td [1] / text () "). extract ()** I get the error. Why I can not insert more than three items in script code? Thanks in advance!